# Reading two xml files simultaneously using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to loop over 2 xml files simultaneously and loading into a list of custom JobModel objects. I am getting NullReferenceException on jobs.ToList() call, obviously my Linq expression is not correct and jobs enumeration is empty.

First xml file

```
tasks.xml 
<objects>
  <object id="X001">
    <property name="jobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpressionString" value="0 00 00 ? * MON-FRI" />
  </object>
  <object id="Addf8ae09bf7a47a891114b8246e3108d">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="TaskExecutor" />
    <property name="cronExpressionString" value="0 00 18 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *" />
  </object>
</objects>
```

Second xml file

```
details.xml
<Tasks>
  <Task id="X001">
    <name>task_1</name>
    <desc>desc_1</desc>       
  </Task>  
  <Task id="Addf8ae09bf7a47a891114b8246e3108d">
    <name>task_2</name>
    <desc>desc_2</desc>    
  </Task>
</Tasks>
```

This is what I have tried in various combinations

```
XDocument tasks = XDocument.Load(@"tasks.xml");
XDocument details = XDocument.Load(@"details.xml");
var jobs = from t in tasks.Root.Elements()
              join d in details.Root.Elements() on t.Attribute("id").Value equals d.Attribute("id").Value
              select new JobModel
            {
                Id = (string)t.Attribute("id").Value,

                CronExpression = t.Descendants("property")
                   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "cronExpressionString")
                   .Select(x => (string)x.Element("value"))
                   .FirstOrDefault()
            };

jobs.ToList();
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Use Descendendants 1) t in tasks.Descendants("object")  2) d in details.Descendants("Task")

Comment: i have tested your code, no exception thrown but `CronExpression` is null.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LogmS6 and if you change `.Select(x => (string)x.Element("value"))` with `.Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("value"))` will work as expected.